# Cocos2d: y-coordinate for touch event greater than that of the touch position

Tags: c++, position, cocos2d-x, frame

I'm learning how to use cocos2d-x by following the gamesfromscratch tutorial. I got to [this part](https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/10/03/Cocos2d-x-Tutorial-Series-Handling-Touch-and-Mouse-Input.aspx) when I noticed this problem with the positioning:

[image: Click on origin with output.]

This basic app basically draws on screen the label "You Touched Here" at the position where you click. Whenever I clicked though, the label would appear well above where I clicked.

In the screenshot above, I clicked at the origin. In the output log, you can see that the touch point (specifically: touch->getLocation(), unconverted) is recorded as (0, 166), where it should be (0, 0).

I tried using other position functions, as well as converting the touch coordinates to other coordinate types, but the problem still persisted.

Below is the code for this simple app:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"

class AppDelegate : private cocos2d::Application {

public:
    AppDelegate();
    virtual ~AppDelegate();

    virtual bool applicationDidFinishLaunching();
    virtual void applicationDidEnterBackground();
    virtual void applicationWillEnterForeground();
};
```

**AppDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
// These header files are not used currently
//#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
//#include "GraphicsScene.h"
//#include "TouchScene.h"
#include "TouchScene2.h"

USING_NS_CC;

AppDelegate::AppDelegate() {

}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate() {

}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {

    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glView = director->getOpenGLView();

    if (!glView) {
        glView = GLViewImpl::create("Hello World");
        glView->setFrameSize(640, 480);
        director->setOpenGLView(glView);
    }

    auto scene = TouchScene2::createScene();
    director->runWithScene(scene);

    return true;
}

void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
}

void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
}
```

**TouchScene2.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"

class TouchScene2 : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();

    virtual bool onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    virtual void onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    virtual void onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    virtual void onTouchCancelled(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    CREATE_FUNC(TouchScene2);

private:
    cocos2d::Label* labelTouchInfo;
};
```

**TouchScene2.cpp**

```
#include "TouchScene2.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* TouchScene2::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = TouchScene2::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

bool TouchScene2::init()
{
    if (!Layer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }

    labelTouchInfo = Label::createWithSystemFont("Touch or clicksomewhere to begin", "Arial", 30);

    labelTouchInfo->setPosition(Vec2(
        Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width / 2,
        Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height / 2));

    auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

    touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(TouchScene2::onTouchBegan, this);
    touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(TouchScene2::onTouchEnded, this);
    touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(TouchScene2::onTouchMoved, this);
    touchListener->onTouchCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(TouchScene2::onTouchCancelled, this);

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener,     this);

    this->addChild(labelTouchInfo);
    return true;
}

bool TouchScene2::onTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    std::stringstream output;
    output << "Touch Pos: (" << touch->getLocation().x << ", " << touch-    >getLocation().y << ")" << std::endl;
    log(output.str().c_str());

    labelTouchInfo->setPosition(touch->getLocation());
    labelTouchInfo->setString("You Touched Here");
    return true;
}

void TouchScene2::onTouchEnded(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    cocos2d::log("touch ended");
}

void TouchScene2::onTouchMoved(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    cocos2d::log("touch moved");
}

void TouchScene2::onTouchCancelled(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    cocos2d::log("touch cancelled");
}
```

One thing to point out is that the tutorial I'm following is several years old (written in 2015 I believe). The author is using version 3.3 beta, while I'm using the latest version 3.17.1. Could this be part of the problem?

And, regardless, how do I fix this issue so that the origin is (0, 0) as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

your TouchScene2.cpp and TouchScene2.hpp seems fine
Problem is in your AppDelegate.cpp where you set

```
 glView->setFrameSize(640, 480);
 director->setOpenGLView(glView);
```

Instead of these try the following code.
You have fixed the FrameSize and hasn't set ContentScaleFactor. Set it as in the Cocos2d-x sample project

```
  director->setOpenGLView(glview);

// Set the design resolution
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);

Size frameSize = glview->getFrameSize();

vector<string> searchPath;

if (frameSize.height > mediumResource.size.height)
{
    searchPath.push_back(largeResource.directory);

    director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(largeResource.size.height/designResolutionSize.height, largeResource.size.width/designResolutionSize.width));
}
// If the frame's height is larger than the height of small resource size, select medium resource.
else if (frameSize.height > smallResource.size.height)
{
    searchPath.push_back(mediumResource.directory);

    director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(mediumResource.size.height/designResolutionSize.height, mediumResource.size.width/designResolutionSize.width));
}
// If the frame's height is smaller than the height of medium resource size, select small resource.
else
{
    searchPath.push_back(smallResource.directory);

    director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(smallResource.size.height/designResolutionSize.height, smallResource.size.width/designResolutionSize.width));
}
```